# Random html tag with type="application/npfido" appearing in source

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, embed

I'm currently testing a site for compatibility across all platforms.

I noticed that on Chrome in Windows, the following appears in the source code *after* the page is finished loading:

```
<embed id="embed_npfido" type="application/npfido" height="0">
```

To be more specific, this doesn't appear in the source - it appears when I right click the page and choose "inspect element". Also, it appears immediately before the `</body>` tag. The only reason I noticed this mysterious embed is because it rendered with a width of 300px and a height of 0px, which very obviously offset my site 300px to the left.

Has anyone seen this before? I searched this issue and nothing came up.

Other details:

- This is happening only on my company laptop, which is a Lenovo T440
- I did not notice this on any other operating system or browser I tested on
- The only external resource being called on the page is a font from Google Fonts (fonts.googleapis.com)
- The embed was rendering with a width of 300px, which I negated with the following code:

  - `embed {display:none;width:0;height:0;padding:0;margin:0;}`

Comment: So what is the source? If this happens to all pages, your browser might have an infection. If not, you need to analyze what is the thing on some page(s) that cause(s) the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this on the bottom of one of my websites, too. It appears to be related to the MFAC extension by Nok Nok Labs in Google Chrome. I disabled the extension and the embed went away.